# If a SAML Token is a Passport, what is an OAuth Bearer Token?

Tags: oauth, token, saml

SAML is much the same as how a passport is handled. You first apply for a passport (Identity enrollment) in your own country (primary IdP provider). Your home country has local regulations on how you receive that passport (SAML Token). Once you receive your passport (SAML Token), you are an authenticated citizen of your country. You can then travel to any other country in the world. Most countries do recognize more than just a passport for acceptance. Some countries that you visit accept your passport much like the basic SAML assertion. Other countries need more information in their acceptance, such as a passport and a Visa, which is a more sophisticated acceptance of a SAML assertion. There is a standardized approach to accepting the authentication of who you are that leads to the design of how the SAML assertion is represented. Once you are accepted to another country, they do not need to manage your passport. You are still required to carry your passport with you. Much the same as a SAML assertion, it is an accepted number of user attributes or rights.

I am trying to understand OAuth using this metaphor. If a SAML Token is a Passport, what is an OAuth Bearer Token?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been trying out the metaphor of the Bar Writstband for Oauth Bearer token...

**Simple Scenario: Token as proxy for authorization session**
You present your driver's license  (grant-type)  which is validated by the bouncer at the front. Once he's sure it's not faked or stolen and that you are of legal drinking age (authorized),  he gives you a wristband to wear that night for access to the bar.  You need a different wristband tomorrow night.

**Extended Scenario: Tokens with Scope limitations as well**
Bar serves all ages, So after accepting your credentials you get a wristband that indicates if you can order alcohol or only soda.  A really cool bar might let you have a "designated driver" wristband and you get free non-alcoholic drinks all night.

In both cases, you only need the credential out once to get the wristband.  After that your access to the bar is granted because you bear the wristband.

Comment: OAuth tokens don't represent an authentication session in any way and are typically issued to and used by 3rd party clients.

Comment: Hans,  true.  Oauth token represent and authorization not authentication session.   I will keep term of session however, as they have a Time To Live so client should be expecting to refresh the tokens regularly,

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of OAuth is "authorization delegation" (which differs from authentication) and the canonical OAuth comparison is a [valet key](https://www.google.com/search?q=valet%20key).

> Valet keys usually can unlock the driver's side door and start the
>   car, but can't unlock the trunk or the glove box. This key is normally
>   used when someone else operates your vehicle, such as a valet parking
>   attendant.

This caters for the fact that a "scoped" token can be issued to a 3rd party so that now the 3rd party can access resources on behalf of the so-called Resource Owner.

FWIW: comparing SAML to a passport is not entirely correct since SAML tokens are also scoped to a particular Service Provider (country in your example).